# Angularjs checkbox confirmation

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, confirmation

I want to confirm when someone unchecks a checkbox. The following function only works every other time. When it first loads its fine. It calls the confirm and if you cancel it leaves the checkbox checked. But if you click it again nothing happens. I'm sure it something simple that I'm missing:

```
$scope.check = function(clickedid) { 
  if (document.getElementById(clickedid).checked === true) {
    return false;
  } else {
   var box= confirm("Are you sure you want to do this?");
    if (box===true){   // yes sure
        return true;
    }
    else{   // cancel
       document.getElementById(clickedid).checked = true;
    }
  }
};
```

and here is the html

```
<lable>Checkbox
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" ng-model="active" ng-change="check('check1')">
</label>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A8Vgk/1726/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its because of `ng-change`, It's working with `ng-click`

```
<lable>Checkbox
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" ng-model="active" ng-click="check('check1')">
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ng-change` Use `ng-click` like this

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <label>Checkbox:
            <input type="checkbox" id="check1" ng-model="active" ng-click="check('check1')">
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/A8Vgk/1727/)

Comment: Thanks for the info but Girdhar Singh Rathore beat you to it. Wish I could accept both answers.